# Test case in python like C programming language

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I write following while loop in python?

```
int v,t;
while (scanf("%d %d",&v,&t)==2)
{
    //body
}
```

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Actually I want to use this loop to solve uva problem 10071 (http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1012)

Comment: If you look up the syntax for a while loop - it is almost the same.

Answer (score 2):

Python being a higher level language than C will normally use different patterns for this kind of situation. There is a deleted question that in fact had the exact same behavior than your C snippet - and thus would be "correct", but it became so ugly a piece of code in Python it was downvoted pretty fast.

So, first things first - it is 2015, and people can't simply look at a C's "scanf" on the prompt and divine they should type two white space separated integer numbers - you'd better give then a message. Anther big difference is that in Python variable assignments are considered statements, and can't be done inside an expression (the while expression in this case). So you have to have a `while` expression that is always true, and decide whether to break later.

Thus you can go with a pattern like this.

```
while True:
   values = input("Type your values separated by space, any other thing to exit:").split()
   try:
       v = int(values[0])
       t = int(values[1])
   except IndexError, ValueError:
       break
   <body>
```

Comment: Indeed, with very rare exceptions, a while loop in Python is not idiomatic unless it starts with `while True:`

Answer (score 0):

This replaces the behavior of your code:

```
import re

while True:
    m = re.match("(\d) (\d)", input()): 
    if m is None: #The input did not match
        break #replace it with an error message and continue to let the user try again
    u, v = [int(e) for e in m.groups()]
    pass #body
```